# Can't run `terminal.integrated.env` command in integrated terminal: "command not found"

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

Following this manual page:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

I would have to set PYTHONPATH "through the terminal settings":

> The PYTHONPATH environment variable specifies additional locations
> where the Python interpreter should look for modules. In VS Code,
> PYTHONPATH can be set through the terminal settings
> (terminal.integrated.env.*) and/or within an .env file.

How do I do that? If I write (I ssh to a Linux server):

```
terminal.integrated.env.linux
```

I get "command not found".

Comment: The `*` is supposed to be a placeholder for the OS. For example, if you are on windows, it would be `terminal.integrated.env.windows`.

Comment: Edited, doesn't work for linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you tried to enter this

```
terminal.integrated.env.linux
```

into the terminal prompt itself, which treated it as a literal command.

What that [guide on PYTHONPATH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable) meant when it said "**through the terminal settings**" was **Visual Studio Code's Integrated Terminal settings**: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings. Specifically the settings under **Terminal** (filtered on `terminal.integrated.env`):

[image: screenshot of VS Code's settings UI with terminal.integrated.env filtered]

Depending on your OS/platform, you put a `terminal.integrated.env.<os>` block in your VS Code's settings.json file to specify the environment variables to inject when using VS Code's integrated terminal:

From https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings:

```json
// Object with environment variables that will be added to the
// VS Code process to be used by the terminal on Linux. Set to  
// `null` to delete the environment variable.
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {},
```

So if you are on Linux:

```json
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
  "PYTHONPATH": "<absolute path>"
},
```

Note: see the [Python docs on `PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) on what exactly needs to be specified here.

Or, as the guide says, you can also specify a `.env` file.